How to load configuration in auth config module from config.json file?
Using https://github.com/damienbod/angular-auth-oidc-client for angular authentication.
Want to load auth config module configuration from config.json file as different configs for different environment need to be used.
I tried following the instructions mentioned below documentation -
https://angular-auth-oidc-client.com/docs/documentation/configuration
Based on above implemented below code-


export const httpLoaderFactory = (httpClient: HttpClient) => {

  console.log("http loader entered ");
  const config$ = httpClient.get('./assets/environments/front.appsettings.json').pipe(
    map((customConfig: any) => {

      return {
        authority: customConfig.authority,
        authWellknownEndpointUrl: customConfig.authWellknownEndpointUrl,
        redirectUrl: customConfig.redirectUrl,
        clientId: customConfig.clientId,
        scope: customConfig.scope,
        responseType: customConfig.responseType,
        silentRenew: customConfig.silentRenew,
        maxIdTokenIatOffsetAllowedInSeconds: customConfig.maxIdTokenIatOffsetAllowedInSeconds,
        issValidationOff: customConfig.issValidationOff,
        autoUserInfo: customConfig.autoUserInfO,
        silentRenewUrl: customConfig.silentRenewUrl,
        useRefreshToken: customConfig.useRefreshToken,
        postLogoutRedirectUri: customConfig.postLogoutRedirectUri
        /* Your config mapping here */
      };
    })
  );

  return new StsConfigHttpLoader(config$);
};

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    AuthModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: StsConfigLoader,
        useFactory: () => httpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient],
      }
    }
    ),
  ],
  exports: [AuthModule],
})
export class AuthConfigModule { }

But getting below error
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: this.loader.loadConfigs is not a function
TypeError: this.loader.loadConfigs is not a function
    at ConfigurationService.loadConfigs (config.service.ts:66:24)
    at ConfigurationService.getOpenIDConfigurations (config.service.ts:46:17)
    at ConfigurationService.getOpenIDConfiguration (config.service.ts:42:17)
    at AutoLoginPartialRoutesGuard.checkAuth (auto-login-partial-routes.guard.ts:33:38)
    at AutoLoginPartialRoutesGuard.canActivate (auto-login-partial-routes.guard.ts:25:17)
    at router.mjs:3348:23
    at Observable._subscribe (defer.js:5:19)
    at Observable._trySubscribe (Observable.js:37:25)
    at Observable.js:31:30
    at errorContext (errorContext.js:19:9)
    at ConfigurationService.loadConfigs (config.service.ts:66:24)
    at ConfigurationService.getOpenIDConfigurations (config.service.ts:46:17)
    at ConfigurationService.getOpenIDConfiguration (config.service.ts:42:17)
    at AutoLoginPartialRoutesGuard.checkAuth (auto-login-partial-routes.guard.ts:33:38)
    at AutoLoginPartialRoutesGuard.canActivate (auto-login-partial-routes.guard.ts:25:17)
    at router.mjs:3348:23

Please help me. Tried different ways of loading it from json. if values are static it works well.

Could you paste the code instead of using the screenshots? why. And also please add relevant parts of the code that is seen in the errors

I have the same config in my project, our only difference is the arrow function
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    AuthModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: StsConfigLoader,
        useFactory: httpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [EnvService]
      }
    })
  ],
  exports: [AuthModule]
})
export class AuthConfigModule {}

useFactory in your case is not expecting async function (returning Observable) but a sync one
